# Polynomial Coordinates

Tags: python, polynomials

I have

```
x = [-10, -7, 2, 6, 11, 12]

y = 3x**2 +2x-1
```

Is there a way to form an array with the corresponding y point like

```
[[-10, y1], [-7, y2],...]
```

Comment: What are y1, y2 in your question ?

Comment: Is numpy acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
x = [-10, -7, 2, 6, 11, 12]


new_list = []
for i in x:
    new_list.append([i,3*i**2+2*i-1])

new_list
```

You will get: [`[-10, 279], [-7, 132], [2, 15], [6, 119], [11, 384], [12, 455]]` as results.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to make your formula a function and apply it to all your x-values in a comprehension:

```
f = lambda e: 3*e**2 + 2e - 1

x = [-10, -7, 2, 6, 11, 12]

points = [(e, f(e)) for e in x]
```

Answer (score 0):

if y1, y2 are y(x[0]), y(y[1]) ...

Then

```
x = [-10, -7, 2, 6, 11, 12]

rslt = [[xi, 3 * xi**2 + 2 * xi - 1] for xi in x]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `map` function to do it:

```
lst = map(lambda x: [x, 3*x*x + 2*x-1], [-10, -7, 2, 6, 11, 12])
print(list(lst))
```

Gives the following result:

```
[[-10, 279], [-7, 132], [2, 15], [6, 119], [11, 384], [12, 455]]
```